# how to upload image using wp_handle_upload

Tags: loop, uploads

hi i am new on WordPress can somebody tell me how can i upload multiple images using wp_handle_upload in a loop

```
for($i=1;$i<count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);$i++){

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['myfile'].$i;

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form'.$i => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
      //  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

        $dir_path= $movefile['url'];


    } else {

        echo $movefile['error'];
    }
}//end loop
```

Comment: try to explane what do you need to do.. not clear what you want to achive..
and do not use $_POST of $_FILES directly inserting data to database.. always sanitize it!!

Comment: sorry i update the code know you check again please

Comment: Still not geting.. what should be done ? what do u mean by 'update multiple meta boxes in a loop' ?
here's an exaple how to upload multiple files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178873/php-uploading-multiple-files

Comment: sorry mistype i want to upload multiple images not multiple metaboxes really sorry i waste your time but please tell me how can i upload multiple images using wp_handle_upload

Comment: see the link in my prev comment, there's an marked answer wich fits your needs.

Comment: wp_handle_upload error in above code

Comment: i check you link but nothing is different same file not move

Comment: do u have necessery peritions on folders ? can you upload media throught dashboard ? what does error says ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's my example of how to upload multiple images:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes',   'my_test_metabox' );

function my_test_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'my_test_metabox', 'File upload', 'my_test_metabox_out', 'post' );
}

add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form' );
function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}

function my_test_metabox_out( $post ) {

    $files = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_files', true );
    if( ! empty( $files ) ) {
        echo 'Files uploaded:' . "\r\n";
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $file['url'] . '" width="100" height="100" />';
        }
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    echo 'Upload files:' . "\r\n";
    echo '<input type="file" name="my_files[]" multiple />';

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_files_save' );

function my_files_save( $post_id ) {

    if( ! isset( $_FILES ) || empty( $_FILES ) || ! isset( $_FILES['my_files'] ) )
        return;

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $files = $_FILES['my_files'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
      if ($files['name'][$key]) {
        $uploadedfile = array(
            'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
            'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
            'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
        );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

        if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
            $ufiles = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', true );
            if( empty( $ufiles ) ) $ufiles = array();
            $ufiles[] = $movefile;
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', $ufiles );

        }
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is code I used up in my plugin, hope you understand it and if any problem you can ask me:-

```
if(isset($_FILES))
    {
        for ($i=1; $i < count($_FILES) ; $i++) 
        { 

            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['question_'.$i];
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var nam = <?php echo "question".$i; ?>
                var namm = $("."+nam).prev().attr('name');

            });
            </script>
            <?php


        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

        if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
            //echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            $filename = $movefile['file'];
        } else {
            /**
             * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
             * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
             */
            echo $movefile['error'];
        }

        // $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory.
        //$filename = '/path/to/uploads/2013/03/filename.jpg';


        // Get the path to the upload directory.
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        $url = $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename );
        echo $url."<br>";

    }           
    }
```

Here is my html code:-

```
    $question =get_post_meta($trivia->ID,'question',true);

     $c = 0;
     $id = uniqid();
    if ( count( $question ) > 0 ) {
        if(is_array($question)){

        foreach( $question as $questions ) {
            if ( isset( $questions['question'] ) ) {


                printf('<p>Question: <input type="text" name="question[%1$s][question]" value="%2$s"> -- <span class="remove_question">%3$s</span><span class="add_answer">   Add Answer</span></p>',   $c,$questions['question'],__('Remove Question'));
                for($i = 1; $i<=count($questions['answers']); $i++)
                {
                    if($questions['answers'][$i]['image'])
                    {
                        printf('<p>Option %5$s <input type="text" value="%1$s" name="question[%4$s][answers][%5$s][answer]"> Status <input type="text" value="%2$s" name="question[%4$s][answers][%5$s][status]"> Image <input type="text" name="question[%4$s][answers][%5$s][image]" value="%6$s"><img src="%6$s" height="100" widht="100"> -- <span class="remove_answer">%3$s</span></p>', $questions['answers'][$i]['answer'] ,$questions['answers'][$i]['status'], __('Remove Answer'), $c, $i,$questions['answers'][$i]['image']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf('<p>Option %5$s <input type="text" value="%1$s" name="question[%4$s][answers][%5$s][answer]"> Status <input type="text" value="%2$s" name="question[%4$s][answers][%5$s][status]"> -- <span class="remove_answer">%3$s</span></p>', $questions['answers'][$i]['answer'] ,$questions['answers'][$i]['status'], __('Remove Answer'), $c, $i);
                    }
                }
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }
    }
}
 ?>
<span id="question_here"></span>
<span class="add_question"><?php _e('Add Question'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
         var countt = 0;
        $(".add_question").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;
            countt = 0;
            $('#question_here').append('<p>Question: <input type="text" name="question['+count+'][question]" value=""> -- <span class="remove_question">Remove question</span><span class="add_answer"> Add Answer</span></p>' );
            return false;
        });
        $(".remove_question").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });


        $(".add_answer").live('click',function(){
            countt = countt + 1;
            $('#question_here').append('<p>Answer <input type="text" name="question['+count+'][answers]['+countt+'][answer]"> Status <input type="text" name="question['+count+'][answers]['+countt+'][status]"><input id="question_'+count+'_answers_'+countt+'_image" type="text" size="36" name="question['+count+'][answers]['+countt+'][image]" value="" /><input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /><span class="remove_answer">Remove</span></p>');
        })
         $('.upload_image_button').live('click',function() {
         formfield = $('#upload_image').attr('name');
         tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

         return false;
        });

         window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         imgurl = $('img',html).attr('src');
         $('#question_'+count+'_answers_'+countt+'_image').val(imgurl);
         tb_remove();
        }
        $(".remove_answer").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

    });
    </script>
</div><?php
```

Comment: your code doesn't solves, if i understood corectly, the question. Is i understood he has `multiple` attr in input..

Comment: Yes he needs this only, try to understand my code, then say anything..

Comment: i do understand your code.. in html you have something like:
`<input type="file" name"question_1" /><input type="file" name"question_2" />` atc., but he has `<input type="file" name"questions" multiple />` and thats big difference in php whan handling upload..

Comment: please send your html code also i want to see your technique

Comment: I have updated my code with html..@HafizUsmanaftab

Comment: Yes but just little edit can work @Maikal

Comment: I do understand that there's a litle to change, but as i see his code example - he doesn't know php.. @dev

Comment: @Maikal is right