# wp_handle_upload returns a critical error response or invalid form submission

Tags: javascript, uploads

Trying to make a plugin that can upload files directly to WP. Despite copying different blocks of code online, it seems determined to not let me upload it.

The way I'm attempting is through a XMLHttpRequest to a php file with `wp_handle_upload`. I append the input file element to a `formdata` and send it through the request. The data that's sent is correct and in order, as i echoed it multiple times to make sure of it, but when it gets to `wp_handle_upload`, it stops working and the network tab says there was a 500 error on the request.

I've tried calling `wp_handle_upload` with only the first parameter but it tells me that the form submission is invalid. I've also parsed the file data to a new variable like what's done [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/201691/224384) but to the same result.

javascript code that handles the input element file:

```js
if ($('#active_p').is(":checked")) personDataActive = 1; //since checked isn't a boolean property, we have to analyze it to get the correct value
else personDataActive = 0;

var personDataUsers = new Array;
var personDataPlaces = new Array;

$("input[name='check_list_user[]']:checked").each(function () {
    personDataUsers.push($(this).val());
})
$("input[name='check_list_places[]']:checked").each(function () {
    personDataPlaces.push($(this).val());
})

//depending on the value of the id, it'll either update or insert a person
if ($('#id_p').val() > 0) id = $('#id_p').val(); //its a new person
else id = 0; //its an already existing person           

let image = $('#profile_picture').prop('files');

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("profile_picture", image[0]);
            
formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', image[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "imageUpload.php",                
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) { console.log("error: " + response)}
});
            
//pass all of the data as an array to make the ajax data more clean. 0 is id, 1 is name, 2 is active, 3 is birthdate, 4 is internalid, 5 is media url, 6 is users and 7 is places

personData = [id, $('#name_p').val(), personDataActive, $('#birthdate_p').val(), $('#internalid_p').val(), personDataUsers, personDataPlaces];

//ajax call to add new person!!!
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxToPhpCalls.php', //the file to send the data to. preferably, leave it on the same folder to avoid problems
    type: 'POST', //it can always be POST even if the intention is getting values, still, it's better to declare the intended type to not accidentaly overwrite stuff
    data: { callFunction : "Insert", personData: personData.join(',')}, //we can't send an array directly, we have to use the .join() function to send it complete
    success: function(response) {
        //the response can be used for debug reasons, since it will return the same data as in Postman
        //alert("Success");
        console.log(response);

        //hide the modal on success so there's a visual cue for the user. if it fails, they can resend the request
        hideCreateModal();

        var total = $("#totalNumber").val();
        $("#totalNumber").val(total++); //add the new person to the total. val()++ doesn't work outside, may work inside the ()
        //console.log($("#totalNumber").val());
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
        resetNewPersonFields();
        ResetTable();
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    },
    error: function() {alert("Error"); $("body").css("cursor", "default");},
});
```

`imageUpload.php` for WP media upload

```php
<?php

//load both to make sure wordpress core functions are loaded
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../wp-config.php' );
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../wp-load.php' );

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

//check if request has required variable
if (! empty($_FILES["image"]))
{        
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['image'], $upload_overrides);
    
    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        $ufiles = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', true );
        if( empty( $ufiles ) ) $ufiles = array();
        $ufiles[] = $movefile;
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', $ufiles );
    }
    exit;
}
else return "No files detected";
```

file input html

```html
<div id="Imagens" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Imagem</label><br>                                
        <input type="file" id="profile_picture" name="profile_picture"><br>
        <label>ou</label><br>
        <a href="#" id="insertImageAnchor" class="button">Adicionar Imagem</a><br>
        <img id="preview" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/983/983213.png" width=350px>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should not be sending requests to a standalone PHP file in your theme/plugin, it's fragile and a major security problem. Use the REST API or admin AJAX instead, then you can handle the request in a filter or callback without dangling files. `imageUpload.php` is a major security mistake. Also check your PHP error log

Comment: I'm conscious of that, I'm using this method to make 100% sure that it is working and can be incorporated to the rest of the code. I'd rather have it isolated to guarantee the problem is in a few lines/places than already implemented throughout multiple files. The error log doesn't point anything out from the file, even with wp_debug activated

Comment: this method will be flagged by a lot of security software and CDN security rules as suspicious, it is not helping your debug process it is hurting you, and also preventing you from using a lot of useful tools. For example Query Monitor has special handling for errors in AJAX and REST endpoints. As for the error, I'd suggest adding in a lot more code, it's not clear what the HTML structure is, so it's difficult to see if the first code snippet is correct

Comment: just added more code related to it, thanks for the suggestion. I haven't noticed if it's been flagged or not, but doing some return "hit"; or echo "hit"; has been successful without any issues, hence being able to pinpoint the issue to the wp_handle_upload() snippet. I'm also still learning some wordpress aspects so I appreciate your tips.

Comment: also, you say `if this then do that` but there are no `else do this` or `otherwise do that` to print out messages. So e.g if `if (! empty($_FILES["profile_picture"]))` is `false` no code is ever run to tell you that, it's just assumed it will work. PS: There are good plugins for handling local uploads of avatars and profile pics, you don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: i know there are and i know im not reinventing something, i did find a lot of material online for a reason. i was asked to do a plugin that also had this functionality in it so I have no choice but to do it. also, the reason why i check if $_FILES is empty is due to calling it on the plugin instantiation. im picking this up after someone else tried to work on it and, according to my superior, did a miserable job. It is at too late of a stage to redo sadly and i can only try and workaround a corpse. without that if statement, it gives a critical error to the whole website.

Comment: (last comment got too long apologies) while i do understand what you're saying by assuming it works, i have removed those messages when i was testing it before coming to the internet for help. as i said before, i was echoing and returning a "hit" message to make sure what was wrong. I had that if statement wrong wrongly before and now it does spark a "true" response when it should

Comment: I meant if you had an `else{}` statement that said something like `"it was empty"` and that came up when it didn't work then that would be really useful in trying to answer the question. Also thanks for adding the rest of the code!

Comment: can I ask, what is the URL this request gets sent from? Is it the root `/`? Because your code references the PHP file but it just states the file, it doesn't provide a full absolute URL or a relative URL

Comment: Request is being sent to the root yes. Since I'm declaring it on startup and the php file is currently on the same folder, I'm able to call it directly. You else{} statement comment is bugging me tho, since the !empty($_FILES[]) isn't giving me problems. It is working as it should and detecting a file in the XMLHTTPRequest. I can add a return "No file detected"; on it to make sure, although I am having a hard time seeing what you're trying to get out of it.

Comment: it eliminates the "it should" or it "shouldn't" and replaces it with an "it is" or "it isn't", right now I have to take your word for it, and I'm a little confused why you're being so defensive about it. Also I think you've misunderstood my comment on the path, your `imageUpload.php` code implies that file is inside a plugin or theme, however, your javascript does not reference a theme or plugin folder, so if you're at `/` it will make the request to `/imageUpload.php` and if you're at `/contact` it will send it to `/content/imageUpload.php` etc, neither of which will work.

Comment: Also a `return` statement in the `else` won't print anything, it would have to be an `echo`. I suspect your `imageUpload.php` isn't being loaded at all. Keep in mind that moving to a REST API endpoint is not that much work and would mean copy pasting the majority of your code into a function and another hook, then changing your JS to point to something like `/wp-json/demonipo/v1/imageupload`. It would not be a total rewrite

Comment: so that I'm clearer, I would expect to see `request.open("POST", "/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/imageUpload.php");` not `request.open("POST", "imageUpload.php");`, and I would have expected it to use `$.ajax` like it does 2 lines below but with a `data: formdata` parameter like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195763/how-to-properly-get-form-data-with-jquery-and-formdata#29195826. Anything you can do to simplify and make things more consistent even the low hanging fruit will make your life easier

Comment: i tend to act and sound more defensive, but it's not in a rude way, so my apologies. the reason for ```return``` and not ```echo``` is due to the later nullifying the whole page load and you'd only see the echoed string. return sends a response back on the network tab of Developer Tools, hence writing it. ```imageUpload.php``` is inside of the plugin i'm making. I declare it on the startup, then I call the javascript file through ```wp_enqueue_script```. I've done the same for the Ajax URL that follows and there's no issue.

Comment: Can you include the invalid form submission in your question? Is that coming from WP or is it coming from the browser dev tools? Does it show the specific line it's coming from or with a stack trace? Is this inside a plugin or inside a theme?

Comment: while i do understand what you mean with using ajax and the requests, it is how I wrote it before starting isolating the problem, I fail to understand how making a request that I've stated before is sending and getting answers back when prompted to, will fix ```wp_handle_upload```. I understand the security problems and the unnecessary code complexity to check this one function, but I never put that into question. ```imageUpload.php``` is loading, it echoes back info if prompted to, it fails when it's asked to use ```wp_handle_upload```.

Comment: I will add it in a little bit, no problems. The invalidation is coming as a response, likely from ```wp_handle_upload``` since it is shown as a json object. there's no stack trace nor line specificity, only that it's invalid. removing the method gets rid of that error. This is inside of the plugin i'm developing

Comment: just dabbled some more to try and replicate the issue. since i wasn't able to get another form submission wrong (which might've been due to a leftover ```</form>``` in HTML which is my fault for not noticing), I went forward and redid the request with JQuery Ajax. While it still returns a critical error when seeing the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools, having no overrides as a second parameter doesn't deliver any response. In fact, the code continues as if everything went well, despite the image not being in the WP media library

Comment: Part of it is that `wp_handle_upload` would normally be available but because it's a standalone file bootstrapping WordPress that assumption might not hold true any longer. Likewise lots of hooks and filters that normally happen got bypassed by being a standalone file. Would it be useful if I ported your profile image to a REST endpoint with some working javascript so you could compare what you have and a working version? I suspect the other half of this is that your files are in the uploads folder but no attachment post is being created, so a related function might work better

Comment: I'm open to any solution, be it changing these files or doing something new. Bonus if it is something I don't know how to do yet, it'll help me learn more about it. If you could do that I would highly appreciate, same way I'm thankful for your help the last 2 days

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Currently untested, but posting here as I write it

The PHP can go in a plugin or your themes `functions.php` and will give you an endpoint at `yoursite.com/wp-json/demonipo/v1/profilephoto` that you can make `POST` requests to via AJAX. Note it assumes you want only logged in users to use this. If that's not the case, change `is_user_logged_in` to `__return_true`. Don't forget to resave permalinks before trying to use it:

PHP:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'demonipo_rest_api_init' );

function demonipo_rest_api_init() : void {
    register_rest_route( 'demonipo/v1' , '/profilephoto/', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'demonipo_rest_profilephoto', // function to run when this is called
        'permission_callback' => 'is_user_logged_in', // only logged in users
    ] );
}
/**
 * Handle the uploading of a profile photo
 *
 * @param \WP_REST_Request $request the AJAX request with all the fields WP recieved
 * @return mixed returns a WP_Error if something went wrong, otherwise it returns an
 *               array with some info about the uploaded file
 */
function demonipo_rest_profilephoto( $request ) {
    // Grab all our parameters, the file and the post to add it to

    // Grab Post ID and check it's legit
    if ( empty( $request['postid'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid', 'You need to tell us which post this is going on' );
    }

    $post_id = $request['postid'];

    // is it really a post though?
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid', 'No post was found using the post ID you gave' );
    }

    $files = $request->get_file_params();
    $headers = $request->get_headers();

    if ( empty( $files['profile_picture'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid', 'No profile photo was found!' );
    }

    $file = $files['profile_picture'];

    // Check the upload worked and is valid:

    // confirm file uploaded via POST
    if ( ! is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', 'Is uploaded file check failed!' );
    }

    // confirm no file errors
    if (! $file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', 'Upload error!' . $file['error'] );
    }

    $att_id = media_handle_upload( 'profile_picture', $post_id );

    // if sideloading failed, return the error so we know what happened:
    if ( is_wp_error( $att_id ) ) {
        return $att_id;
    }

    $new_data = [
        'file' => basename( wp_get_attachment_image_url( $att_id, 'full' ) ),
        'url' => wp_get_attachment_image_url( $att_id, 'full' ),
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    ];

    // All is good! Update the post meta
    $ufiles = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', true );
    if( empty( $ufiles ) ) {
        $ufiles = [];
    }
    $ufiles[] = $new_data;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', $ufiles );

    // return any necessary data in the response here
    return rest_ensure_response( $new_data );

}
```

Important notes:

- I noticed it used `$post_id` in the PHP but it was never defined anywhere so it had no way to know which post to update. Make sure to include a `post_id` field in your formdata.
- `wp_handle_upload` will move the file into the right place, but it won't create attachments, so I swapped it for `media_handle_upload`. This is the missing piece you needed for it to show in the media library. I've also set it to attach it to the post you pass it
- This article was very informative in writing this: https://firxworx.com/blog/wordpress/adding-an-endpoint-to-wordpress-rest-api-for-file-uploads/ you may recognise some parts of the error checking
- lots more error checking, it should never be triggered but if it does then the REST API will pass it back to your javascript and jQuery will kick up an error you can read
- I wasn't sure off the top of my head how to grab the mimetype so I just hardcoded it to `image/jpeg`. I also told it to return the fullsize image, but WP will also have created thumbnail sizes etc
- If you can, try to store the attachment ID rather than the filename/URL, it'll make migrations much easier
- This article/gist was also informative, though I would recommend using a PHP based block rather than a shortcode these days: https://gist.github.com/ahmadawais/0ccb8a32ea795ffac4adfae84797c19a

That last gist has JS code that's close to what you want:

```js
// Check, if a file is selected.
if ( 'undefined' === typeof( jQuery( '#profile_picture' )[0].files[0] ) ) {
    alert( 'Select a file!' );
    return;
}

// Grab the file from the input.
var file = jQuery( '#profile_picture' )[0].files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append( 'file', file );

// TODO: Add Put the post ID in your HTML somewhere
var post_id = jQuery( '#post_id' )
formData.append( 'post_id', post_id );

// Fire the request.
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: '/wp-json/demonipo/v1/profilephoto',
    method: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData
} ).success( function ( response ) {
    console.log( 'success!' );
    console.log( response );
} ).error( function( response ) {
    console.log( 'error' );
    console.log( response );
});
```

**You will need to add a hidden input with the post ID named `post_id` with the same ID and name alongside that file input for this to work.**

e.g.

```php
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?php ECHO POST ID HERE ?>" />
<input type="file" id="profile_picture" name="profile_picture"><br>
```

There is one thing I left out that I don't think is necessary, the REST API nonce. Normally for authenticated requests you have to pass a nonce, which isn't hard but I don't think you need to. If you do, the API will just tell you by saying the request is forbidden, if so let me know. How to do that is covered in some of the links I added so it isn't too much work.

I've also used `jQuery` instead of `$` as the jQuery that comes with WordPress uses no conflict mode by default, but feel free to change that.

---

As a general guide, you can take a random PHP file like this:

```php
<?php
//load both to make sure wordpress core functions are loaded
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../wp-config.php' );
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../wp-load.php' );

echo "Hi there " . $_GET['name'];
```

And convert it into a pretty URL REST API endpoint like this:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'demonipo_rest_api_init' );

function demonipo_rest_api_init() : void {
    register_rest_route( 'demonipo/v1' , '/randomphp/', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'demonipo_randomphp', // function to run when this is called
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ] );
}

function demonipo_randomphp( $request ) {
    return 'Hi there' . $request['name'];
}
```

Comment: I just tested it and it does return an authentication error. tried to check what part of the code needed the token but I'm too used to CURL requests, so I'm confused as to where I should add it. I'm going to try and figure out how to deal with ```$post_id``` when this starts working, I'm not a fan of hidden inputs so if I find a way to avoid them I'll go with that. With that out of the way, this is so awesome!!! I was expecting something more difficult but it really does look easy. the comments also help a lot and get a giggle out of me. this is really dope!

Comment: switch to `__return_true` for now, as for hidden inputs you shouldn't be afraid of them, they're a part of the HTML spec for a reason and serve a valuable purpose. Otherwise you have to insert them as data attributes and it isn't as semantic. Ideally your UI would work as just plaintext HTML, or at least be close to it for accessibility purposes. I'm not sure how I can help with retrieving the post ID though as I'm not sure how the rest of that page works or the setup you have but if you find any other issues with my code let me know and I'll try to update it, it hasn't been tested thoroughly

Comment: it does seem to be working, at least in terms of saying im sending the data wrong eheh. I've switched the code so it is incorporated with the rest of the plugin, while being able to make a curl call that sends the token im saving for other calls that need it. while i don't have a problem anymore with authentication, I do have regarding ```$post_id```. the way it's working is that it is looking for a post that already has that ID right? since i want to add the image to WP, can I reverse it to ```if ( $post instanceof WP_Post ){"not allowed since there's already one with that id!"}```?

Comment: the goal there is to make sure the post actually exists, after all you can't update the meta of a post that does not exist, e.g. on a site with 5 posts would it make sense to say upload this photo, and the post ID is `1967845`? Inverting it wouldn't make sense as you're not creating a post. Remember `update_post_meta` and `get_post_meta` need the ID of the post you're updating/getting the meta from, that's why `$post_id` is there and why it's checking if the post exists or not

Comment: while the website was down, i tried the if statement i mentioned before, and I've come across ```if ( ! is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] )```. since the file doesn't have this when appended, could it be changed to be related to its name? the file object appended has: 
```lastModified:
lastModifiedDate:
name: 
size: 
type: 
webkitRelativePath:```
being a curl request, ```is_uploaded_file``` is gonna say it is false since it doesn't recognize it as a HTTP Post request right? the file object isn't recognized with ```$_FILES``` so I'm doing ```$request['profile_picture']```

Comment: No, I think you've misunderstood what that function does, what you've just said does not make sense. That check is confirming that the temporary file it's being given is indeed an uploaded file from the user, and not just some random file on the server that was already there. It looks like you're encountering issues, but rather than sharing them with me you're trying to make workarounds and sharing the workarounds. Try to avoid X Y problems, share the problem first, not proposed solutions

Comment: update the meta of a post that does not exist? but, I don't wanna update anything, only add the image. I could make the postid 0 so it has no relationship to a post, like it says [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) couldn't i?

Comment: you misunderstand, when you upload the image, it has an attachment ID, and that ID is saved by retrieving a post meta named `my_files`, adding the files details to the list, then saving the new version of the list back to `my_files`. This happens in both your code and my code. After all how does the site know which files the user has uploaded? Was that what you intended? Post meta requires a post ID, you cannot have post meta without a post. You cannot use `0` as the post ID

Comment: some workarounds were mostly for safety reasons, didn't want to share the authentication token with javascript, as that seems pretty dangerous. I basically did what you suggested initially of making this snippet apart of the plugin, not an isolated instance. If the sent file won't have the `'tmp_name'` component, and since i only call it when inserting or updating data, is that check necessary? Doesn't seem like anything else would call it and try to add already existing images

Comment: If `tmp_name` is missing then that means the media handle sideload will probably fail. Unfortunately telling you what to do requires me to do things I can't do for several hours. You shouldn't be putting hardcoded authentication tokens in your code, and nonces are not authentication tokens and are not an issue as they're unique to you and only work if I was logged in as you, in the specific browser session on your computer

Comment: don't worry about that, the code you wrote is already a massive help. I'm going to try and do some more research about what you told me and understand better how I should be handling the issues I'm having, since my confusion is mostly due to not knowing how media uploading works. Token isn't hardcoded, my superior made a rest api connection to request it and I've previously coded to store it when you logged in.